# How to loop through items in MovieClip in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I am trying to do this in as3

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var clip = "markerMC" + i;
    this.scoreGridMC[clip]._visible = false;
}
```

but I get compile errors all the time.

Any help,

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as3, taskinoor's answer is as3 only if you set those names as movieclip instance names in the flash IDE...

Option #1: getChildByName("childName");

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var clip = "markerMC" + i;
    this.scoreGridMC.getChildByName(clip).visible = false;
}
```

for the above to work you would need to set the mc.name when you create the movieclips to something like mc.name = "markerMC"+0; and +1 and ... all the way to +8; for the respective movieclips.

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); // or new MarkerMC() or whatever it is in library properties for the mc
this.scoreGridMC.name = "markerMC0";
```

For reference, to go through the all the children of a movieclip try something like (this is option #2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.scoreGridMC.numChildren; i++) {
    this.scoreGridMC.getChildAt(i).visible = false;
}
```

Once again, taskinoor's answer is valid as well but you have to create the mc's manualy trough the flash IDE and assign them instance names in their properties panel...

Also, when you get a compile error, google it until you find the solution on the net. The net is there, you just have to use it. Also, you might want to post those compile errors in the question for obvious reasons as well as your as3 code in case this is not it.

Good luck.

Comment: getChildByIndex is wrong. It's get getChildAt(index). +1 anyway cause you've got the concept right and explained some thing that I think were lacking in the other answer. :)

Comment: I have set the names in the IDE as markerMC0 to markerMC7, tried the first option using getChildByName, but it did not work... any ideas, i looked all over the web and tried tons, but no luck

Comment: Ok I was wrong, error in my Movie Clip names, option 1 works treat, thanks.

Comment: +1 for the details explanation. I have deleted my answer. That is almost of no use now.

Comment: @Ascension Systems thank you for the correction, you are right, i have no idea where I got getChildByIndex from... gringoLoco007 it seems you and I were lucky as the IDE sets the "name" property of the movieclips as well, I forgot about that little detail :). At least i think it does if my memory serves me right.